# Fragment error when open another application

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

Please check the error below. I am really confused what is happening. I am using viewpager in Tab activity. And, I have a button which opens gmail of mobile after opening that application crashes reporting this error:

```
> **08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment EventOneTimer{52a01374} is
> not currently in the FragmentManager 08-22 22:57:42.356:
> E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment(FragmentManager.java:563)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.saveState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:188)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1265)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:12213) 08-22
> 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):    at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2592)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2598)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2598)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2598)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2598)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2598)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2598)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2598)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2598)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:12196) 08-22
> 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):    at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1605)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1198) 08-22
> 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):    at
> android.app.ActivityGroup.onSaveInstanceState(ActivityGroup.java:66)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.app.TabActivity.onSaveInstanceState(TabActivity.java:112)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1147)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3177)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3236)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141) 08-22
> 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-22
> 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-22 22:57:42.356:
> E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 08-22
> 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-22
> 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 08-22 22:57:42.356:
> E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> 08-22 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 08-22
> 22:57:42.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12123):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**
```

Comment: I think this is because you can still using fragmentManager to do some operation on your fragment, after your app was sent to background. Generally, we should not make transition of fragments when app is in background.

Comment: Are you doing anything with fragments in onPause or in onActivityResult?